# API for FCC electronic equipments radio emissions

Tags: data-request, telecom

The (USA) Federal Communications Commission maintains a database of all the equipment they test, [located here](https://www.fcc.gov/oet/ea/fccid).

I am looking for an API ( REST, SOAP, etc...) to query and fetch the data.

My queries are low volume; I don't want to scrape the data from HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCC's OET Laboratory API has a `getFCCIDList` method call, all though I'm not sure how helpful that will be without a list of IDs. Seems like a bunch of busy work, exactly what you are trying to avoid by not scraping it.
[OET Laboratory Services API Documentation (PDF)](https://apps.fcc.gov/eas/comments/GetPublishedDocument.html?id=217&tn=384645)
[`getFCCIDList` API Call Example for ID 'OPS'](http://apps.fcc.gov/OETLabServices/getFCCIDList?fccId=OPS)

[FCCID.io - Searchable FCC ID Database](https://fccid.io/) has a lot of exposed IDs, and I would start there if I were trying to amass a complete list. It may also be worthwhile to contact them and inquire about accessing the master list/database.

Comment: unfortunately fcc.gov API ( getFCCIDList ) only list the grantee ( company ), but not the product name !

Comment: maybe i'm confused but if you click on the API call example for ID 'OPS', and snag first ID 'OPS1', then plug 'OPS1' into FCCID.io, you get https://fccid.io/OPS1 which looks like it has product information in it....

Comment: yes FCCID.io shows product name but not on fcc.gov and I cannot trust fccid.io as I trust fcc.gov

Comment: i hear you on trust, as its not the canonical source, but it looks pretty solid...